# mongoose cursor slows down until it stops

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, cursor, kue

I have a node.js application that uses kue jobs to go over large collections using mongoose cursors.

kue job configuration:

```
function childJob(cid, name, dataset, type, link, line, market, done) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    mongoose.model(dataset).count({processed:{$ne:1}}, function(err, total){
        console.log('total', total);
        var job = jobs.create('child', {
            type: 'CHILD',
            cid: cid,
            title: name, 
            dataset: dataset,
            kind: type,
            link: link,
            line: line,
            market: market,
            current: 0,
            total: total
        });
        job
           .on('complete', function() {
                deferred.resolve({
                    done: true,
                    job: job.data,
                    success: true
                });
           })
           .on('failed', function() {
                deferred.resolve({
                    done: true,
                    job: job.data,
                    success: false
                });
           })
           job.save();
           return deferred.promise;
        });
    }
```

Whenever a child job is started:

```
jobs.process('child', 10, function(job, done) {
    var count = 0;
    mongoose.model(job.data.dataset).find({processed:{$ne:1}}).lean().batchSize(1000).cursor().eachAsync(function(record){
        functions.workRecord(record, job.data.link, job.data.line, job.data.market, myStats[job.data.line+job.data.market],  function(stats){
            count++;
            job.data.current = count;
            job.update();
            job.progress(count, job.data.total, record);
            if( count == job.data.total ){
                myStats[job.data.line + job.data.market] = stats;
                done();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Over time the number of records that `cursor().eachAsync()` decreases dramatically. Going from processing 100 a second to about 1 or 2 records across several seconds and then a complete stop.

Is this a configuration issue? How can I set the query to have a consistent flow of records in the cursor over time?

EDIT1: eventually I get the following error:

> (node:61193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cursor not
>   found, cursor id: 90600322391
>       at Function.MongoError.create (/home/sigma/SigmaCWCDataAnalysis/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what was happenning is that the cursor was timing out.

Solution was setting the find() query to {timeout:false} like the following:

```
mongoose.model(job.data.dataset).find({},{timeout: false}).lean().cursor()
```